# Java - Performance difference between static and non static

Tags: java, class, static, initialization

How big is difference in performance, when class is initialized every time and methods are not static (`new Class()`) or methods in this class are static and usage of them is like `Class.method()`?

Example code:

```
//File Class1
public class Class1{
    public static void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("Static method, usage: Class1.myMethod();")
    }
}

//File Class2
public class Class2{
    public void myNonStaticMethod(){
        System.out.println("Non static method, usage: Class2 class2 = new Class2(); class2.myNonStaticMethod();")
    }
}
```

Which one will be faster? Static or method with class initialization?

PS. Sorry, if I did any mistake. English is not my main language. :P

Comment: there is no real issue there. the point of choosing one over the other is not the efficiëncy, but rather the purpose and requirements.

Comment: So which one is better to use when I carry about performance? I do not need "super" in some cases, so if static is faster, I can use it there, but is it good?

Comment: Why would you want to create a new instance of `Class2` for each call anyways? How is the method related to an instance of that class? Do you want the method to be overridable?

Comment: For same reason when you initialize String everytime when you are creating new block of text. Note that it is just an example code, I am just asking about performance difference :P

Comment: I do not want any override. I am just asking what option is better to get access of method in class with greatest performance score.

Comment: As others already said static or not isn't something you should decide on performance criteria but wether or not the method needs an instance of an object to work properly. If the methods doesn't need an object and its internal state make it static.

Comment: So static is great in API's with void methods, but not for methods, that will return objects?

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on what you are trying to achieve. The point of making a method or a variable static is for when you want to be able to access them without necessarily creating instances of their parent classes. For example:

You can have a class for calculating Body Mass index. Within that class you can have a method `x` for converting Kilograms to Pounds. Now one can one to do a conversion of Kilograms to pounds but not want to calculate their Body Mass index. In this kind of scenario it makes sense to make that method `x` static, so one can do a conversion of Kilograms to pounds without creating a new instance of `x`.

So it's not about performance really, but about usage.

Comment: Thank you for answer! So, If I am creating something like API, the best option is make methods static.
But when I am creating, for example, PlayerData (that will hold all player data like location, name), it is better to make them just public and export initialized class to other classes using class constructor instad of using, for example, static hashmap to collect this all data separately?

Comment: For something like `PlayerData` that will hold all player data like location, name. Yeah you should create a new instance. But basically static methods/variables are used when what they do don't depend on things like instance variables